# Inserting JS value into HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that retrieves browser details (version, what browser, OS etc) but i'm just using cookies enabled for this example. I want to be able to break my results into a table with 2 columns but my question is can anyone aid me in how do i get the JS to insert the result into the second column?

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Cookies Enabled:</td>
            <td id="Cookie"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<body>
```

Javascript:

```
 //Cookies enabled
    var Cookies; 
    {
        if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
            Cookies = "True";
        } else {
            Cookies = "False";
        }
    }
var Cookies = Cookie;
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("Cookie").innerHTML = Cookies;
```

```js
//Cookies enabled   
var Cookies; {
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    Cookies = "True";
  } else {
    Cookies = "False";
  }
}
var Cookies = Cookie;
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Cookie").innerHTML = Cookies;
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cookies Enabled:</td>
      <td id="Cookie"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <body>
```

Expected result:

```
   Cookies Enabled:      True
   Operating System:     Windows
   Javascript Enabled:   True
   etc.
```

I already have the script written for getting the values, i just need help inserting them into a table. Thanks

Comment: You don't need an `if`/`else`, since `navigator.cookieEnabled` returns a Boolean (`true`/`false`) anyway; just use `Cookie = navigator.cookieEnabled;` (or skip the variable, and just directly *use* `navigator.cookieEnabled`). But where are you stuck?

Comment: Just wondering, do you (want to) use jQuery or pure JS?

Comment: @MemetOlsen I'll use anything at this stage :P

Comment: You code is confusing, but the real problem is this line `var Cookies = Cookie;` should be removed. Otherwise you set `Cookies` to reference HTML td element node. http://jsfiddle.net/Lotm5cjw/

Comment: @dfsq yes apologies and we have a winner, that worked just fine. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why doesn't your answer work:

```
var Cookies;

{
  if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    Cookies = "True";
  } else {
    Cookies = "False";
  }
}

// you're over-writing your found Cookies variable with
// the value of Cookie, which you haven't assigned and
// is therefore retrieved from the browser, in most (perhaps all)
// browsers if an element with this id exists (as it does, here)
// the uninitialised variable will be a reference to that Node
// otherwise (if not initialised) it'll be undefined.
var Cookies = Cookie;

window.onload = function() {
    // here you're correctly attempting to assign the variable,
    // but it's the wrong variable:
    document.getElementById("Cookie").innerHTML = Cookies;

// here you should be, but aren't, closing the assignment of the
// window.onload function.
```

Your corrected code (removing (apparently) unnecessary curly braces, a needless variable-assignment and closing the function properly:

```js
//Cookies enabled   
var Cookies;

if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
  Cookies = "True";
} else {
  Cookies = "False";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Cookie").innerHTML = Cookies;
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cookies Enabled:</td>
    <td id="Cookie"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
//Cookies enabled

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Cookie").innerHTML = navigator.cookieEnabled;
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cookies Enabled:</td>
    <td id="Cookie"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The column called cookie?
I'm unclear on what you want to do exactly but.

```
document.getElementByID('Cookie').innerHTML="text"+variable;
```

That should get you able to wrote the variable to the second table field.

Comment: should be getElementById instead of getElementByID

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var Cookies; 
    {
      if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        Cookies = "True";
      } else {
        Cookies = "False";
      }
    }

    var Cookie = Cookies;
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("Cookietd").innerHTML = Cookie;
        };
</script>
</head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Cookies Enabled:</td>
          <td id="Cookietd"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      </body>
</html>
```